# Replacing the contents of tag with another tag using Java script

Tags: javascript

I want to replace the value of the tag

```
<h2>..</h2>
```

with the content of the tag

```
<h3>..<h3>
```

I wrote the script like this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div>
            <h3><span><!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:addwidget[1]/custom:text[1]"} -->
                        <strong>Section Text</strong>
                    </span> </h3>

                <h2>
                        <a title="Google" href="http://google.com">google.com</a>
                    </h2>
            </div>  

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var x=document.getElementsByTagName("div");

        for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
        var children = x[i].getElementsByTagName('h2');

        var demo= children["demo"].innerHTML;


        var childd =x[i].getElementsByTagName('h3');

        var all=childd["all"].innerHTML;



        children["demo"].childNodes[0].innerHTML=all;
        childd["all"].innerHTML=null;
        }

        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Rule:

In the above example I want to replace "google.com" with the text in the `<h3>` tag.
But I am not getting the output.

Output needed.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div>

                <h2>
                        <a title="Google" href="http://google.com">
                        <span><!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:addwidget[1]/custom:text[1]"} -->
                            <strong>Section Text</strong>
                        </span> 
                        </a>
                    </h2>
            </div>  


</body>
</html>
```

I am not getting the exact output.
I have used for loop because I want to do it for every occurrence of div tag.

Can any one look into it and suggest how to correct it.

Thanks.

Comment: Use Jquery man ! this is a piece of cake with jquery

Comment: @ubercooluk: It's a piece of cake without it too. :-P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be as simple as:

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = document.getElementById('all').innerHTML​;​
```

**EDIT**: With your new HTML code, you can replace all `<h2>`s with `<h3>`s like so.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i = 0, len = divs.length; i < len; i++){
    var div = divs[i],
        h2 = div.getElementsByTagName('h2'),
        h3 = div.getElementsByTagName('h3');

    if(h2.length === 1 && h3.length === 1){
        h2[0].innerHTML = h3[0].innerHTML;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I want to replace every occurrence of it. So I Implemented for loop. Can you also add for loop implementation in it.

Comment: @User222: Every occurrence of what?  IDs are unique, so there's only one occurrence (that's what your example shows).  What does your HTML *really* look like?

Comment: @User222 - You can only have one `<h3 id="all">` in your HTML.

Comment: @Rocket.Sorry for the wrong input. I have edited the question. If its not having any Ids and taking tag name into consideration, for every occurrence of div tag, I want to replace the contents of <h2> with <h3>. Can you please look into it.

Comment: @Thank you. But I want to get the "section Text" as link. But I didn't see section Text as link to "http://google.com" as per the question.

Comment: @User222: You want "section text" to be a link?  That's not exactly "copying the h2 to the h3".  Though I guess it is in your question.  I guess then you could try `h2[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML` instead.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) Solution:

```
$('#demo').html($('#all').html());
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but probably because jQuery isn't the answer to everything.